# how to take mean of the column of tuple

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a tuple which I convert to numpay array

```
dt=np.dtype('float,float') 
ar=np.array(val,dtype=dt)
```

Like this

```
ar=[(0.08181818181818182, 0.394023569023569) (0.0, 0.0)
 (0.16785714285714287, 0.3227678571428571)]
```

I want to take columns mean of this array ( 0.08+0+0.16)

tried this code

```
np.mean(ar, axis=0)
```

but its giving this error

```
 print np.mean(ar, axis=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2878, in mean
    out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 65, in _mean
    ret = umr_sum(arr, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

Comment: Why you don't make 2d array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

dt=np.dtype('float,float')
ar=np.array([], dtype=dt)

ar=[(0.08181818181818182, 0.394023569023569), (0.0, 0.0),
    (0.16785714285714287, 0.3227678571428571)]

print(np.mean(ar, axis=0))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[ 0.08322511  0.23893048]
```

**UPDATE**

Shame on me! These lines are redundant:

```
dt=np.dtype('float,float')
ar=np.array([], dtype=dt)
```

Since there is a reassignment on the next line, `ar` becomes `list` instead of `numpy.ndarray`.

So either you should use just

```
ar=[(0.08181818181818182, 0.394023569023569), (0.0, 0.0),
    (0.16785714285714287, 0.3227678571428571)]

print(np.mean(ar, axis=0))
```

or, you need:

```
ar = np.array(
    [
        (0.08181818181818182, 0.394023569023569),
        (0.0, 0.0),
        (0.16785714285714287, 0.3227678571428571)
    ])

print(type(ar))
print(np.mean(ar, axis=0))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[ 0.08322511  0.23893048]
```

Comment: Any idea how we can take mean of the end result eg  `a=[ 0.08322511  0.23893048]` and `b=[ 0.167889 0.356343]` mean of a and b

Comment: Or convert the result output to an ordinary array